# Saving and retrieving URL from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, url

I am trying to save an URL in mysql db and get it back in my application. It gets saved properly.

```
http://i.>/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/$(KGrHqZHJC4E8fW,EPnUBPN1zoBtIQ~~60_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007
```

but while retrieving, all the '.' operators in the URL gets replaced by

```
http://i�domain�com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/$�KGrHqZHJC4E8fW�EPnUBPN1zoBtIQ~~60_1�JPG?set_id=8800005007
```

Is there a way to remove those special characters. Attaching the create script for the table..
Im getting the url from the result set.
rs.getString(image)

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `livedeals` (
  `ItemID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `deal_like` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `deal_dislike` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET armscii8 COLLATE armscii8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

any help would be helpful.
thanks.

Comment: Remove `CHARACTER SET armscii8 COLLATE armscii8_bin` from your table definition - UTF-8 is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't change the character set of the table, then you could get that field the following way:

```
SELECT CAST(image AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) AS image2 FROM livedeals
```